# tfidf vectorizer gives different shape

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using tfidfvectorizer from sklearn.

My understanding based on the docs is such that this piece of code should work

```
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(df, df_target):
    train, train_labels = df.iloc[train_index], df_target.iloc[train_index]

    test, test_labels = df.iloc[test_index], df_target.iloc[test_index]
    tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False)
    train = tf_transformer.fit_transform(train)
    test = tf_transformer.transform(test)


    print test.shape
    train.shape
```

However, it gives 2 different shapes

```
(9871, 14489)
Out[20]:
(39481, 28211)
```

Am i misunderstanding something? The test transform should give the same shape as the train?

Comment: try printing train.shape and test.shape before transforming by vectorizer. If it's different, then you are going right

Comment: Yes it is different

Comment: Then obviously, you'll get different shape!

Comment: @abhinav why? i dont understand. Its just a series for both train and test

Comment: Do your test and train series has different size?

Comment: Sorry i resolved it. Now i having an issue of UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 93: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137864/discussion-between-abhinav-and-aceminer).

Comment: @aceminer I am facing a similar issue. the train and test tdifdfs have different shape. Can you kindly let me know how you resolved it?

Comment: @SriPallavi sorry it’s been a while. Cannot remember if I managed to fix it